# Get zip code from longitude and latitude coordinates

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I have a zipcode table, and I was wondering how can I make a query that takes in `latitude` and `longitude` coordinates, and returns a zip code from it. how can this be done?

Here is my table structure:

```
mysql> describe zipcodes;
+-----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | bigint(20)            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| zip       | mediumint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| longitude | varchar(15)           | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| latitude  | varchar(15)           | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| city      | varchar(25)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| state     | varchar(25)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| county    | varchar(25)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| zipClass  | varchar(25)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-----------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to be able get a zipcode that is the closest to the `longitude` and `latitude` coordinates.

Comment: This is a U.S. database which is already populated with 42k zipcodes.

Comment: `SELECT zip FROM zipcodes WHERE longitude = your_longitude AND latitude = your_latitude`? Not sure what's your issue here

Comment: that won't work, since lat/long are exact coords of a zip.

Comment: @tsabz I want to retrieve the data. I am going to use gps, and send coords to the server the server will then take those coords and return a relevant zipcode.

Comment: Look up "haversine" or "great circle" formula.

Comment: Not exactely what you are looking for but could help: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql

Comment: How accurate does this need to be?  A single point on the map isn't an accurate representation of the zone the zipcode includes...  Would the 'closest' zip code location be good enough?

Comment: @PinnyM yes, I just want close thanks.

Comment: A relational database really is not a suitable way of trying to achieve this - You're looking to identify a point by a minimum distance criteria

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query I found, it seems to work.

```
SELECT zip, city, state, ((
    ACOS(SIN(-094.076163 * PI() / 180) * 
    SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + 
    COS(-094.076163 * PI() / 180) * 
    COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * 
    COS((44.661216 - longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()
) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM zipcodes ORDER BY `distance` limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your table, you'd need to calculate the distance between the given latitude and longitude and the latitude and longitude of each zip code, and then choose the smallest value.

(Obviously, finding the "closest" zip code doesn't mean that the given point is actually within the zip code boundaries.)

The query below has one implementation of the "great circle distance" calculation, but it's  going to be an expensive operation, since this calculation will be performed for every row in the `zipcodes` table:

```
SELECT ACOS( COS(RADIANS( d2.latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( d1.latitude ))
           * COS(RADIANS( d2.longitude ) - RADIANS( d1.longitude ))
           + SIN(RADIANS( d2.latitude ))
           * SIN(RADIANS( d1.latitude ))
           ) * 3958.82 AS distance_miles
     , d2.*
  FROM zipcodes d2
  JOIN (SELECT 44.9800 AS latitude, -93.2636 AS longitude) d1
 ORDER BY distance_miles DESC
 LIMIT 10
```